# Ruby: Write a value to a specific location in CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm still fairly new to coding and I'm trying to learn about manipulating CSV files.

The code below opens a specified CSV file, goes to each url in the CSV file in column B (header = url), and finds the price on the webpage.

Example data from CSV file:

```
Store,URL,Price
Walmart,http://www.walmart.com/ip/HP-11.6-Stream-Laptop-PC-with-Intel-Celeron-Processor-2GB-Memory-32GB-Hard-Drive-Windows-8.1-and-Microsoft-Office-365-Personal-1-yr-subscription/39073484
Walmart,http://www.walmart.com/ip/Nextbook-10.1-Intel-Quad-Core-2-In-1-Detachable-Windows-8.1-Tablet/39092206
Walmart,http://www.walmart.com/ip/Nextbook-10.1-Intel-Quad-Core-2-In-1-Detachable-Windows-8.1-Tablet/39092206
```

I'm having trouble writing that price to the adjacent column C (header = price) in the same CSV.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

contents = CSV.open "mp_lookup.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol
contents.each do |row|
  row_url = row[:url]
  goto_url = Nokogiri::HTML(open(row_url))
  new_price = goto_url.css('meta[itemprop="price"]')[0]['content']

#----
#In this section, I'm looking to write the value of new_price to the 3rd column in the same CSV file

#----

end
```

In the past, I've been able to use:

```
in_file = open("mp_lookup.csv", 'w')
in_file.write(new_price)
```

But this doesn't seem to work in this situation.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have to use CSV for this? CSV is a variable record length format so altering a row generally means copying the file row by row and altering the desired row along the way. CSV is a fine format to use for data interchange but it makes a terrible database.

Comment: I suppose I do not have to.  I've seen code along the lines of File.open, file.readlines.each, line.split(',')[1], etc.  Do you think something like that would work better?

Comment: I just realized now that I should clarify that I do have to use a CSV or text file, but I do not necessarily have to use the CSV gem or whatever.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you use `File` or `CSV`, you'll still end up reading the file record by record, altering the records you need to change, and then writing them all out again. Or import your CSV into an SQLite database, do your work in SQLite, then dump the results out to CSV when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the help mu.  I'll look into using SQLite

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can refer to the `:price` column in the CSV file, just like you refer to the `:url` column.  Try this code to set the price in the CSV object in memory:

```
row[:price] = new_price
```

After you've read through all of the records, you'll want to save the CSV file again.  You can save it to any filename, but we'll simply overwrite the previous file in this example:

```
CSV.open("mp_lookup.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  contents.each do |row|
      csv << row
  end
end
```

In a real production environment, you'd want to be more fault tolerant than this, and preserve the original file until the end of the process.  However, this shows how to update the values in the price column for each row, and then save the changes to a file.